# My receiver doesn't receive alarm manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm try to send a notification at specific time, I search online some solution but code won't work.

I user alarm manager with BroadcastReceiver, but BroadcastReceiver never receive my alarm. Why?

Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

MainActivity.class:

```
    ...
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);       // hour is an int selected from user
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);          // minute is an int selected from user
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

My Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Log.d("ALARM RECEIVER", "Alarm received");

    // do stuff...
    }
}
```

--edit -- Add full manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signin"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InformationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_information"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AcquiringDataActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_acquiringData"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GraphActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_graph"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_note"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MealActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_meal"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhoneNumbersActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_phoneNumbers"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_information"
        android:parentActivityName=".InformationActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.InformationActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RecoveryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recoveryPassword"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionAnswerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recoveryPassword"
        android:parentActivityName=".RecoveryActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.RecoveryActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RecoveryActivitySetPassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recoveryPassword"
        android:parentActivityName=".QuestionAnswerActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.QuestionAnswerActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NoteDetailedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_note"
        android:parentActivityName=".NoteActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.NoteActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WriteNoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_note"
        android:parentActivityName=".NoteActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.NoteActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailedPhoneNumbersActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_phoneNumbers"
        android:parentActivityName=".PhoneNumbersActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.PhoneNumbersActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ModifyPhoneContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_phoneNumbers"
        android:parentActivityName=".DetailedPhoneNumbersActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.DetailedPhoneNumbersActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateNewContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_contact"
        android:parentActivityName=".PhoneNumbersActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.PhoneNumbersActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AllInsertionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_all_insertions"
        android:parentActivityName=".GraphActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.GraphActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchFoodActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_food"
        android:parentActivityName=".MealActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.daniel.diabetegestazionale.MealActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

<service
    android:name=".AlarmService"
    android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your whole Manifest.xml

Comment: Did you placed the receiver in application tag ?

Comment: Place the receiver in application tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

`</application>
<service
    android:name=".AlarmService"
    android:enabled="true" />
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>`

to

`<service
    android:name=".AlarmService"
    android:enabled="true" />
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
</application>`